# Calculate the average of a filtered list/column with a condition (libre office calc)

Tags: average, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, subtotal, sumproduct

I'm trying to calculate the average of a filtered list (J23:J1026), but with a condition.

The condition is to calculate the average of the values < 0.

I was able to get the **count** of the values < 0 with the following formula in cell D19:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(J23;ROW(J23:J1026)-ROW(J23);0));(J23:J1026<0)+0)
```

But I am not able to calculate the average of the values < 0.

The result should update if the list is filtered in another column.

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the reason `AverageIf()` exists? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642

Comment: @Dominique Sir, OP is talking abt filtered list. Do `AVERAGEIF()` will work with a filtered data? Or can array be used within `AVERAGEIF()` when the list is filtered?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya so averageif() or averageifs() and add the filtering conditions as needed.

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, try to filter the range as mentioned in OP. And not abt just filtering conditions. There are two conditions in the OP --> • `< 0` and • when the list is filtered.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya well I copied the numbers you used in your answer - except for your row 23 which is not visible and I get the same result of -2.1333, which means I used the same filtering condition you did - unless you have missed something?

Comment: This is the first line in the OP. _I'm trying to calculate the average of a **filtered list** (J23:J1026), but with a condition._ Filtered list and visible cells means same, only that you have taken those which are less than 0 in the filtered list, what if op wants to exclude some of the `<0` as in mentioned in OP **filtered list**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya "*This is the first line in the OP. I'm trying to calculate the average of a filtered list (J23:J1026), but with a condition.*" which is a single condition stated as "<0".

Comment: @SolarMike sir, you are missing **`filtered list`** but with a condition so there is `2` conditions actually. You could refer the comments posted by OP below my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Formula suggested is related with `Excel` Tags which was earlier posted in OP(**Original Post** - Please see edits of the post), however OP(**Original Poster**) later changed the tags.

Try using `MAP()` function with `SUBTOTAL()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, J23:J32, AVERAGE(TOCOL(x/((MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,SUBTOTAL(103,y))))*x<0),2)))
```

---

Not sure about `Libre Office Calc` as per OP since `LET()`, `MAP()` and `LAMBDA()` are not available functions of the same, hence could try this way as well:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(J23:J32/(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(J23:J32,ROW(J23:J32)-MIN(ROW(J23:J32)),,1))*(J23:J32<0)),""))
```

---

Since I am not familiar with `Libre Office Calc` hence as per the comments of OP, I am borrowing the idea that the given formula in above will work when it is committed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

Comment: Wow that's working amazing in Excel, thanks! 
I tested it out in my Libre Office Calc sheet and unfortunately in Calc there is no Let() function. Do you know how it could be achieved differently?

Comment: @electricar sorry i dont know about `Libre Office Calc` btw the OP is tagged using `Excel` and `Excel Formula`

Comment: yeah, I am the OP and I thought it would be the same for Excel and Libre Office Calc.
I somehow need to find this functionality for Calc.

Comment: @electricar place this formula in one place: `=IFERROR(J23:J32 / (MAP(J23:J32; LAMBDA(y; SUBTOTAL(103; y))) * (J23:J32 < 0)); 0)` and then use `=AVERAGE()` function on the resulting cell of the formula, may be that way works in Libre

Comment: thank you, unfortunately map() and lambda() are not available in Libre

Comment: @electricar i have an update, could you try: `=AVERAGE(IFERROR(J23:J32/(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(J23:J32,ROW(J23:J32)-MIN(ROW(J23:J32)),,1))*(J23:J32<0)),""))`

Comment: thank you very much. Unbelievable how many different approaches you are presenting. In Excel this works great as well, unfortunately I am getting an "#VALUE!" error in Libre and I am struggling to find out why...

Comment: oh wow it worked! I had to enter the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER into the cell. Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

So using averageif() as suggested:

[image]

```
AVERAGEIF(A6:A13,"<"&0,A6:A13)
```

No iissues with averageif() with a condition of <0.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working if I filter another column.
The calculated value stays the same.

Comment: @electricar you should nt change the tag once two solutions are already posted instead should raise a new question. Otherwise users will think we have posted solutions for Libre Calc which the solutions are not related with

Comment: @electricar then use averageifs() where you can add as many conditions based on multiple columns and conditions such as E:E >75 etc etc But I don't know if Libreoffice has averageifs() as when i originally answered you were asking about Excel.